# How to test adding indexes performance in Rails console?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, postgresql

I want to add indexes to increase my app performance.

I would like yo measure the performance of added indexes.

For example i have following table:

```
create_table "classifications", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "app_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
  t.string   "targit_type"
  t.integer  "targit_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I think about adding here three indexes:

```
# Classification
add_index :classifications, :app_id, name: "index_classifications_on_app_id"
add_index :classifications, :user_id, name: "index_classifications_on_user_id"
add_index :classifications, [:target_id, :targit_type], name: "index_classifications_on_targit_id_and_targit_type"
```

So I would like to measure the performance of that change.

How will be the best way to do that?
Should I do that in Rails console?

```
>> Agreement.find_by_user_id_and_review_id(User.last.id, Review.last.id)                                                                              
  User Load (14.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Review Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" ORDER BY "reviews"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Agreement Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "agreements".* FROM "agreements" WHERE "agreements"."user_id" = 2064 AND "agreements"."review_id" = 1557 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) or in older versions, plain `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

This will not only give you query timing, it'll tell you which indexes are being used.

You should also use `pg_stat_user_indexes` as sufleR points out.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to find queries on that table and measure times before and after creating indexes.

PostgreSQL offers some statistics about tables and indexes ([9.1 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html)).
I like to use pg_stat_user_indexes to view all statistics about indexes.
Try to view that and I think that you will find very useful information there.
Also you should check pg_stat_user_tables for check how many times is full table scan running on tables.